# testdisk: finds primary NTFS boot partition, but can't mount/access data/boot

Tags: ntfs, testdisk

Ran Ultimate Boot CD on a Windows XP machine that's in a reboot loop (safe mode not working), checked disk health, etc. It's fine.  Ran testdisk, finds the NTFS primary boot partition, can browse files, etc. but after rebooting back into UBCD, still can't see the partitions in any of the File Management utilities.

Been so long since I've done any of this kind of stuff -- do I need to fix the MBR *after* writing the partition table in testdisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, well, the first thing i'd do would be to inspect the actual **BSOD** - that is to enter the option after **F8** to stop restarting when encountering an irrecoverable error. Then i'd google parts of the error and see where that leads me.

I'm not quite sure what **UBCD** enables you to do, but if this is a filesystem related (**NTFS**) error, then i'd first try "mounting" the partition with **ntfs-3g** off a **live** distro (such as **debian live**). If that does not succeed - then i'd run **chkdsk /F /R** over it and see the error reported when mounting the partition, again.

If your partition table is corrupted - then, yeah, **testdisk** should be able to restore it.
**fixmbr** to restore the **MBR**, then **fixboot** to restore the boot manager/loader (**ntldr**).

But, ofc, focus on mounting the filesystem successfully first. Regarding disk health, well, you'd need **smartmontools**, namely **smartctl -A /dev/sd?** to inspect it's SMART attributes and **smartctl -t short/long** to setup selftests.

Comment: SMART attributes are fine; forgot about `chkdsk /r`, will try that.

Comment: @gravyface: sorry, if you don't mind me asking - could you post the whole export of SMART attrib to pastie.org or a similar resource?

Comment: I can once chkdsk completes.

Comment: chkdsk for the win.  Wow.  Feel pretty silly for not remembering that.  Thanks.

Comment: np, glad it helped.